# ag grid server side sorting with pagination

Tags: vue.js, ag-grid

I'm really confused about how to implement server side sorting with Ag Grid while having pagination and infinite scrolling options. I have the following use cases specified for our application implementation of ag grid

- 5 page sizes (20, 50, 100, 200, All)
- All = grid height of 300 rows and infinite scrolling
- Each specific page size means we retrieve the # of items from our API call that is = to page size. So for example, a page size of 50, means each API call per page, retrieves 50 items.
- The above statement means that navigation to a new page of the grid = a new call to API to retrieve data

Based on all of this, I also need to implement server-side sorting. What I need to do, is the following

- User clicks a column header
- Header click triggers a function that calls our API with a sort parameter and returns results
- Grid refreshes with new (sorted) results

From what I've read so far, the two primary requirements are that *sorting* and *enableServerSideSorting* parameters are set to true. However I'm not sure what to do after that. Is it possible to modify the *getRows* ag grid callback, to call my API each time instead of the function looking only at cached results?

I'm just looking at what the conventional process is to handle a situation like this. Any help is appreciated and thank you in advance.

Comment: Any update on this ! I am also looking for the same